# Too many re renders on if

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When the view is charging I need to wait for an state to change so I have to make multiple calls to the api but if I do it like this

```
const [vWaitForCreditInfo, setvWaitForCreditInfo] = useState(true);
if (vWaitForCreditInfo === true){
    setLoading(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      paycheck()
    }, 5000);
  }
  else{
    setLoading(false);
  }


  async function paycheck() {
    const vUserId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('vUserId');
    const response = await ForceApi.post('/GetUserStatusController.php', {vUserId});
    setvWaitForCreditInfo(response.vWaitForCreditInfo);
  };

return(
 {vWaitForCreditInfo == false ? (
   <Text style={styles.disclaimer}>
     ¡Hola! Por el momento no podemos otorgarte el préstamo ya que no cumples 
     con nuestras políticas internas, te recomendamos ponerte al corriente en 
     tus cuentas e intentar de nuevo en un mes. Cualquier duda quedamos al 
     pendiente, ¡saludos!
   </Text>) : null}
);
```

i get the too many renders problem, i tried to wrap it up on an use effect but it just execute once and dont look for the api again

the problem is that the disclaimer is not showing
any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I need to give you a tip: please do not use ternary operator for the [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) do this instead (even with ternary operator your code could not work cause you have a syntactic error ):

```
if (!vWaitForCreditInfo) return null

 return (
    <Text style={styles.disclaimer}>
      ¡Hola! Por el momento no podemos otorgarte el préstamo ya que no cumples 
      con nuestras políticas internas, te recomendamos ponerte al corriente en 
      tus cuentas e intentar de nuevo en un mes. Cualquier duda quedamos al 
      pendiente, ¡saludos!
    </Text>
 )
```

Coming to the main issues you've faced:

- You should make the API calls inside the [useEffect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) and you should not pass the dependencies in order to render only one time (when component render).
- You should not make the if statements in the RFC, you should use it inside the useEffect hook.
- Your component is in circle of updating the state and will re-render in infinite way.

Enough talk my solution is:

```
const [vWaitForCreditInfo, setvWaitForCreditInfo] = useState(true);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    const  paycheck =  async () => {
        setLoading(true)
        const vUserId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('vUserId');
        const response = await ForceApi.post('/GetUserStatusController.php', {vUserId});

        if (response.vWaitForCreditInfo !== vWaitForCreditInfo) {
            setvWaitForCreditInfo(response.vWaitForCreditInfo);
        }

        setLoading(false)
    }

    paycheck()
 }, [])


 if (!vWaitForCreditInfo) return null

return (
   <Text style={styles.disclaimer}>
    ¡Hola! Por el momento no podemos otorgarte el préstamo ya que no cumples 
    con nuestras políticas internas, te recomendamos ponerte al corriente en 
    tus cuentas e intentar de nuevo en un mes. Cualquier duda quedamos al 
    pendiente, ¡saludos!
 </Text>
)
```

Comment: I would also be sure to return a function from the useEffect hook (can throw errors when unmounting if not)

Comment: yes you're right, but this is very crucial when you have a listener in your use effect hook.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

```
React.useEffect(() => {
 if(!vWaitForCreditInfo) {
  return setLoading(false)
}
},[vWaitForCreditInfo]);
```

And trigger your vWaitForCreditInfo like that

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    paycheck();
,[vUserId]);
```

Something like that, depending on when you need to reload

Comment: this doesnt work, but thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

```
  const [vWaitForCreditInfo, setvWaitForCreditInfo] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
     if(vWaitForCreditInfo) {
          paycheck()
     }
  }, [vWaitForCreditInfo]);

  async function paycheck() {
    const vUserId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('vUserId');
    const response = await ForceApi.post('/GetUserStatusController.php', {vUserId});
    setvWaitForCreditInfo(response.vWaitForCreditInfo);
  };
```

Here everytime the banking veryfication is made, the useEffect will trigger. It will only make a new verification with a new API call.